# image.complete always returns true

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm looking to do some logic when an image is loaded AND it isn't in the browser cache. Problem is, using the `complete` boolean from jQuery always returns true -- even if the image isn't in the browser cache. Code snippet:

```
var elem = $('.my-img');
console.log(elem.prop('complete'));
```

and this always logs true in the console, both on Chrome and Firefox. Are there any workarounds, or am I using the value incorrectly?

Comment: If an image is loaded, why wouldn't it be in the cache?

Comment: @Sébastien: Incognito/private browsing, pushed out by other things, ... Remember, there are four hard problems in computer science: Cache invalidation, naming things, and off-by-one-errors.

Comment: Of course... Anyway I don't know how we could check that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ...when an image is loaded AND it isn't in the browser cache...

As far as I know, there's no way to check whether an image is in cache. `complete` doesn't tell you that; it tells you the first part (mostly), that the `img` element is available (e.g., the image has been loaded, which means it *may* be in cache) or is broken (or [a couple of other things](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/semantics-embedded-content.html#dom-htmlimageelement-complete)).

---

This is probably a tangent:

Your code is checking the `complete` flag of the **first** img matching the `.my-img` selector. Apparently that image is complete (broken, or loaded). If you want to check **all** images matching that selector, you'll need a loop of some kind, perhaps `map`:

```
var flags = $(".my-img").map(function() { return this.complete; }).get();
```

Of course, any `false` flags in that array could be outdated the instant you get it, as images are loaded out of band with the JavaScript code.

Comment: Ah, then I misunderstood `complete` completely... Thank you for the quick answer -- I'll keep hacking to find a workaround.